# Integration between two Salesforce orgs

Tags: integration, attachment, apexrest, rest-service, callout

Trying to transmit ticket number and attachment as HttpRequest body but not able to pass attachment from Org1 and retrieve attachment in Org2. I can get the value of ticket number but not the attachment in the Org2.

Making callout from Org1 to Org2 using  below class.

```
public class SendAttachmentToORG2 {
        @future(callout=true)
        public static void Attach(String cId,String AttId)
        {   

            Service_Req__c  myTkt = [SELECT Id,Name from Service_Req__c WHERE Id =: cId limit 1];        

            String TicketNumber = myTkt.Name;

            Attachment att= [select Id,body from Attachment where Id=:AttId limit 1];
            Blob attBody = att.body;

            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
            String endPointURL = 'callout:ORG2Sandbox/services/apexrest/v1/TktAttachment/';
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setEndpoint(endpointURL);
            req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            Map<String,String> postBody = new Map<String,String>();
            postBody.put('ticketNum',TicketNumber);
            String reqBody = JSON.serialize(postBody);
           // req.setBodyAsBlob(attBody);  ????
            req.setBody(reqBody);
            Http http = new Http();
            req.setTimeout(60000);
            String responseData = '';
            try {
                HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);  
                responseData = res.getBody();
                System.debug('Response Data: '+responseData);
            } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
                System.debug('Error in webservice call');
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Apex Rest class in Org2.

RequestBody debug returns ticket number but not attachment.
How to pass and retrieve attachment ?

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/TktAttachment/*')   
global with sharing class AttController {

@HttpPost   
  global static String createAttachment() {

     RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
     system.debug('requestBody :::::'+ req.requestBody.toString());

     return 'Attachment Created';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working.

```
public class SendAttachmentToORG2 {
        @future(callout=true)
        public static void Attach(String cId,String AttId)
        {   

            Service_Req__c  myTkt = [SELECT Id,Name from Service_Req__c WHERE Id =: cId limit 1];        

            String TicketNumber = myTkt.Name;

            Attachment att= [select Id,body from Attachment where Id=:AttId limit 1];
            Blob bBody = att.body;
            String AttBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(bBody);
            String AttName = att[0].Name;
            String AttType = att[0].contentType;

            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
            String endPointURL = 'callout:ORG2Sandbox/services/apexrest/v1/TktAttachment/';
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setEndpoint(endpointURL);
            req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            Map<String,String> postBody = new Map<String,String>();
            postBody.put('TicketNum',TicketNumber);
            postBody.put('AttachmentBody',AttBody );
            postBody.put('AttachmentName',AttName);
            postBody.put('AttachmentType',AttType);
            String reqBody = JSON.serialize(postBody);
            req.setBody(reqBody);
            Http http = new Http();
            req.setTimeout(60000);
            String responseData = '';
            try {
                HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);  
                responseData = res.getBody();
                System.debug('Response Data: '+responseData);
            } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
                System.debug('Error in webservice call');
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/TktAttachment/*')   
global with sharing class AttController {

@HttpPost   
  global static String createAttachment() {

      RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
      blob b = req.requestBody;    

      Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(b.toString());

      String TicketNum = (string)m.get('TicketNum');
      String sAttachment = (string)m.get('AttachmentBody');
      Blob  bAttachment = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(sAttachment); 

      String AttName = (string)m.get('AttachmentName');
      String AttType = (string)m.get('AttachmentType');

      list<Case> cList = [select id,Ticket_ID__c from Case where Ticket_ID__c= : TicketNum limit 1 ];

      if(cList.size() > 0){
      Attachment cAttachment = new Attachment();
      cAttachment.ParentId = cList[0].Id;
      cAttachment.Name = AttName;
      cAttachment.ContentType = AttType;
      cAttachment.body =  bAttachment;
      insert cAttachment;

      return 'Created Attachment on Case';
      }
      else{
        return 'Ticket Not Found';  
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you connecting through named credentials here? i am new to named credentials and would like to hear from you on why not OAuth authentication

Comment: @AnilShivaraj Yes am using Named Credentials..Check this blog posts for more details http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-to-salesforce-integration-using-named-credentials-in-just-5-lines-of-code/  http://blog.enree.co/2016/03/salesforce-apex-lets-play-with-named.html